# mod_rewrite ignoring line in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file 
It is ignoring my rewrite rule?

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#this is the line not working
RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]+) /news-article.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I am really new to rewrite rules. All the examples I found said this should work. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: that's a very... furry.... url... done any basic debugging, like bumping up the rewrite logging level so you can see what's happening as a request gets processed?

Comment: yes, I have removed all the lines but the one not working but it will not catch it.

Comment: Can you clarify what URL are you trying and what is not working? Also tell where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: so what I need it when you www.domain.com/news-article.php?id=202 to be like www.domain.com/new202/ but now it never looks at those rules.

Answer (score 0):

If these rules are in an htaccess file, you need to remove the leading slash from the regex. The URI used for the match has the leading slash stripped off since Apache version 2.

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news-article.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Additionally, you want this rule **below** the other rule you have because that one redirects the browser, which will mess up this rewrite.

Comment: yes I tried this and it is like the rule is ignored. Any debug tips?